# is it possible to manipulate drawn object and geometries in canvas in direct2d?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, animation, graphic, direct2d

I am willing to operate some drawn graphic object in canvas like animating, moving, transforming , changing the overlapping order, resizing, recoloring, making transparency of some object with respect to other objects. is it possible to do those things easily without the need of handling all the effects that each operation has on other object in direct2d?

Comment: It's all done by hand. D2D is just drawing. If you want it to do thing, you need to handle that yourself.

Comment: is there a library to do things like that ?

Comment: Not... as far as I know. And it depends on your needs. You'll probably have to implement it yourself.

Comment: so do you mean every game developer company that needs such features design and implement such library from the scratch?

Comment: Big ones build in-house game engines. Others use commercial ones like Unreal Engine or Unity, or custom versions. But it's hard to have one solution match all in game interfaces.

Comment: so how does ms windows handle the windows on the screen when they overlap and drag and minimize? shouldnt windows utilize some api's for handling such frequently used operation? if the answer yes then why not sharing such api's to developers?

Comment: :) Ok... you need to go learn. You're mixing canvases with windows.

Comment: actually both use the same namespace! drawing namespace !